# Angular injects module causing bind fails

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-resource

I have recently started a new project on angularJS.

I have an index.html which basically render all the script files when started.
There is a ng-view inside, the home.html will be loaded by ngRoute and is binded to a controller called HomeCtrl.

When I inject $resource to my HomeCtrl, the ng-bind on my html becomes not working, while removing the $resource it will work.

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$resource', function ($scope, $resource) {
     $scope.testText = 'testabc';
}])
```

I have tried inject something else, the behavior is also the same, the ng-bind will not work. There is no error shown in the browser console. May I know how can I trace what is actually happening?

Files as below:

https://plnkr.co/edit/P92PLlrWoqINpfeju5X1?p=preview

Comment: You did not inject $scope. So $scope.testText is actually $resource.testText in order to dependency injection order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add '$scope', angular tries to inject the objects in the order they are set.

Change

```
 app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$resource', function ($scope, $resource) {
     $scope.testText = 'testabc';
 }])
```

to

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', function ($scope, $resource) {
     $scope.testText = 'testabc';
}])
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If it solved your problem, consider accepting it as answer! Thx :D